# how to make JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve for a specific endpoint out of two?

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

I have my Jenkins server with reverse proxy. I want the slave agents to connect at the private IP of the master VM, but access Jenkins via reverse proxy url.
The Jenkins Url under "Jenkins/Manage/Configure" is holding the reverse proxy url for various good reasons.
When I execute the jar command in the agent with the private IP, the JnlpAgentEndpointResolver finds two endpoint in the list to resolve.

java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://172.17.0.4:8080/computer/agent-1/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 32487hdhkjhdskjhdhadhkjshd8y7dsjbdeud

INFO: Locating server among [https://my-reverse-proxy.url.com/, http://172.17.0.4:8080/]

Feb 14, 2020 4:25:36 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve

INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]

But, it selects endpoint: my-reverse-proxy.url.com over 172.17.0.4:8080, and for some reason it ends up with exception. However, it does successfully connect with private IP.
How can i make sure that the JnlpAgentEndpointResolver selects the specific endpoint over another?

Thanks in advance,